# Como criar um método de extensão para o tipo de uma classe em VB.NET

Tags: .net, entity-framework, vb.net, reflexão, métodos-estáticos

Estou criando uma estrutura MVC que irá trabalhar semelhante ao Entity Framework dentro de um projeto VB.NET onde eu criei um atributo chamado `TableAttribute` que irá definir o nome da tabela e dos *schemas* para o *model*, assim:

```
Namespace Models.DataAnnotations
  <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)>
  Public Class TableAttribute : Inherits Attribute

    Sub New(Name As String)
      Me.Name = Name
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Schema As String = "dbo"

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Assim, eu posso acrescentá-lo em meus *models* que irão servir para fazer a camada de dados da aplicação:

```
Imports Models.DataAnnotations
Namespace Models
  <Table("Usuario", Schema:="Sistema")>
  Public Class UsuarioModel
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Login As String
    Public Property Senha As String
  End Class
End Namespace
```

Além disso, eu tenho um Módulo que é relacionado ao `Namespace.Models`que mantém uma série de funções de extensão para os modelos:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Namespace Models
  Public Module ModelsExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Function GetTable(Obj as Object) as String

      Dim type As Type = Obj.GetType()
      Dim temp As TableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(TableAttribute), True)(0)

      If (temp IsNot Nothing) Then Return $"{temp.Schema}.{temp.Name}"

      Return $"dbo.{type.Name}"

    End Function
  End Module
End Namespace
```

Meu problema é que, para que eu consiga pegar o nome de uma tabela qualquer, eu sou obrigado a instanciar a mesma fazendo um `new Usuario().GetTable()`.

Existe alguma forma de eu estender um método diretamente para o tipo `Usuario`? O resultado que espero ficaria assim: `Usuario.GetTable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como, afinal métodos de extensão são feitos para operar em cima de uma instância. Se não quer operar em cima de uma instância então não faz sentido fazer isto.

Provavelmente você só quer um método estático regular passando o tipo, ou provavelmente deveria ser um método genérico, mas não posso afirmar.

C# deve ter algum parecido com método estático de extensão na versão 8 ou7 9.

Comment: se fosse um método estático regular que passo o tipo, como eu faria isso em VB.NET? em cada classe eu implementaria isso?

Comment: Não, é a mesma coisa, só que passaria o tipo e não a instância.